# Sklearn: using TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have data `class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'` looks like

```
  (0, 55)   1
  (0, 54)   1
  (1, 55)   1
  (1, 54)   1
  (1, 55)   1
  (1, 54)   1
  (2, 945)  1
  (2, 945)  1
  (2, 950)  1
  ...
```

I need to transform it.
First I try to use

```
sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer
```

but it doesn't improve value of `roc_auc`
And next I try to use

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=13, max_df=0.5, min_df=0.1, ngram_range=(1, 2))
data_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(data)
```

But it returns an error

```
AttributeError: lower not found
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: `TfidfVectorizer` is the equivalent of `CountVectorizer` followed by `TfidfTransformer`. Presumably, you are passing it `data`, which is a sparse-matrix that comes from `CountVectorizer`. So, you are suppose to use `TfidfTransformer`, which, you already did...

Comment: You're supposed to pass text to a TfidfVectorizer...

Comment: depending on what model/data you're using, tfidf may well not improve your model performance